# Can accelerated charged particle gain energy from charged medium?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

Suppose a charged particle is moving in a medium. If it is accelerated, it is well known that it radiates energy (even in the vacuum). I was wondering if the charged particle would accelerate through an electrically charged medium (i.e, a swarm of stationary charged particles) how would it behave? Would it radiate more energy to the medium or is there any  possibility that it could gain energy too?

Comment: It will do what charged particles do in electromagnetic fields... which can range from the trivial to sixty years of research into plasma physics. As asked this is way too broad.

Comment: Actually my question is not that broad. I just wanted to know if there exists any phenomenon that an accelerated charged particle gains energy from a charged medium. It would be great if l am given some references.

Comment: You mean like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_acceleration?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Can you suggest some elementary level book/review where I can find these type of phenomena?

Comment: Not sure there is anything "elementary" about these kinds of effects. Fermi-acceleration, in particular, is something that I can't quite wrap my intuition around, either. There is very little in plasma physics that I would call easy. I can only suggest you go to the library and start digging into the available literature and see what you can find. Maybe the plasma accelerator technology could be a start, too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_acceleration.